Why is the more flexible task often given to the left hand on the guitar when most people are right-handed?
The majority of humans in this world are right-handed, which means they are typically better at performing meticulous tasks with their right hand than with their left. However, if we examine the design of guitars, we see that the more intricate tasks are often assigned to the left hand rather than the right. This is particularly evident in the case of rhythm guitar, where the left hand must frequently change finger positions to form new chords, while the right hand is often tasked with the relatively simpler job of strumming a consistent pattern throughout the piece. Of course, I am not referring here to less frequent cases where the right-hand part is exceptionally complex—I am just talking about the general situation.
It’s interesting that the piano, unlike guitars, seems to correctly accommodate the idea that the right hand should be given a more complicated job. While the piano is designed to allow an equal level of complexity for both hands, in the majority of compositions, the right-hand parts are often more versatile and challenging to execute. Meanwhile, the left hand is typically responsible for providing accompaniment, which is usually much simpler. Again, I am not talking here about complicated classical pieces, but just about the general trend.
So, the question is: why is the more versatile and demanding role often given to the left hand on the guitar, while the majority of people are right-handed?

Can we clarify the styles that this question relates to? In my experience simple strumming with the right hand is hardly representative of guitar playing, classical or most other styles. Even rhythm guitar is rarely 'simple' in terms of strumming. For other styles (e.g. fingerstyle) it is often the case that simple chords fretted by the left hand demand right hand acrobatics to play the song.

I asked a very similar question some years ago, but cannot find it. Making this a possible dupe.

Please un-accept my answer. I'd like to delete it.

@Aaron - Why do you want to delete it?

It's too near-sighted. Strumming of stringed instruments is very, very old, and the piano case is now in the linked questions list.

@Aaron - Okay then, I will unaccept it, but I must let you know that it helped me a lot and, in fact, DID answer my question.

I see. Then tell me more about how it helped, and perhaps I can make an appropriate revision. Maybe in the chat room.

@Aaron - (1) Your answer helped me learn that stringed musical instruments—at least unbowed ones like the lute and others—were in fact developed in such a way that many versatile tasks were assigned to the right hand rather than the left. It seems that strumming all the strings at once, which is now very common for rhythm guitar, was a rather rare technique at the time. Instead, techniques like plush arpeggios on a single chord and rapid tremolos on one note, achieved through rapid plucking and finger changes with the right hand, were much more common.

@Aaron - (2) Moreover, it appears that only with technological advancements and the invention of softer strings were additional techniques, such as tapping and string bending, introduced—thereby giving the left hand more responsibilities.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

It's important to recognize that while the question is not being asked in the context of classical music, the instruments were developed in that context. Thus the right/left handed orientations were based on the musical demands being made on those instruments and their predecessors.
In the rhythm guitar case, the left and right hand roles were determined before there was such a thing as rhythm guitar (in the sense intended by the question) — so for someone to play rhythm guitar, they either had to learn the instrument as it existed, or reinvent the instrument, requiring anyone else who wanted to play rhythm guitar to also learn this specialized tool. Classical guitar music makes intricate use of the strumming hand, so it would be natural for the right hand to take that role.
For piano, the answer is in the question. Low sounds are used in Western music for accompaniment, while higher sounds are used for melody and embellishment — generally the more complex, featured task. So again, using the right hand for that purpose makes sense.
For a more generalized version of this question, see Why do our instruments go from bass on the left to treble on the right, and not the opposite?.

Classical and romantic guitar is not really an original instrument, it developed based on baroque guitars, lutes and other instruments. This answer suggests that primary use of these instruments was always plucking and not strumming, and not providing chordal rhythm accompaniment, which I'm afraid is not true. Moreover, in my answer I argue that the OPs assumption that the fretting hand does more work is not true.

Yeah, there are plenty of instruments either strummed or plucked monophonically with a plectrum across global music history


This is particularly evident in the case of rhythm guitar, where the left hand must frequently change finger positions to form new chords, while the right hand is often tasked with the relatively simpler job of strumming a consistent pattern throughout the piece. Of course, I am not referring here to less frequent cases where the right-hand part is exceptionally complex—I am just talking about the general situation.

I'm afraid this is very mistaken.

The rhythm is often considered the most important feature of music, and it is natural to give the task to the more skilled hand - both for plucking and for strumming. The plucking/strumming hand is also responsible for dynamics and big part of articulation.
I would consider in general the plucking/strumming hand doing more work, typically requiring more force, larger amplitude of movement and engaging more muscles. See e.g this examples:

baroque guitar used in baroque repertoire, featuring both plucked and strummed sections:



classical guitar used in romantic repertoire. Of course tremolo technique is kind of extreme example, but somehow this is one of the most recognizable classical guitar compositions



acoustic guitar, banjo, mandolin and a violin used in a bluegrass song (in particular see the solos in the second part of the recording):



electric guitars used in a metal song, with fast rhythm parts






Of course with so much music ever written you can find exceptions, but I feel these examples are fairly representative.

I talked about general situation, not the cases that you have presented here, especially the classical ones.

@brilliant then I'm afraid I don't understand what do you have in mind, in particular when you mention "rhythm guitar".

I mean you just take any amature who has only learned how to play a few songs - he wouldn't have much trouble with the strumming hand, but he definitely be still struggling with the left hand changing chords from one to another.

@brilliant perhaps an amateur who has only learned a few songs is not a typical person for whom the instruments developed over the course of millennia. Yes, I agree at the beginning simple strumming may seem simpler, I can also agree there are compositions, or even styles of playing with more emphasis on the fretting hand, but in most mainstream applications it is the plucking/strumming hand doing more physical work.

@brilliant The underlying mistake is: When assigning tasks to dominant vs. non-dominant hand, it's not that the dominant takes the "meticulous" small tasks; it takes the big tasks requiring larger motions, more force or power. Think about a computer gaming setup using a mouse and a keyboard simultaneously; most will give the mouse to their dominant hand, requiring larger motions, while the non-dominant handles the small motions of fingers on keys. As for beginners finding it challenging, that's just because learning any complex new physical skill that we're unaccustomed to is challenging.

@brilliant “I talked about general situation, not the cases that you have presented here” and “you just take any amature who has only learned how to play a few songs”. You appear to be saying that the latter is the general case, and each example here is just an edge case? Hardly any instrument is designed to be played mainly by amateurs who just learned to play. This answer gives you clear demonstrations on how right hand dexterity matters a lot for guitar, and your answer to that is seriously “this doesn’t count, they aren’t amateurs”?

@Lazy - (1) "This answer gives you clear demonstrations on how right hand dexterity matters a lot for guitar"

I, in fact, strongly disagree with this. As a guitar player myself—and not just an amateur—I can tell that, with the exception of the very first video (on the baroque guitar), none of the other examples clearly show that right-hand dexterity outweighs that of the left hand.

To start, none of the examples provided in this answer are strictly about rhythm guitar.

@Lazy - (2) Even in the last video featuring Metallica, I would refrain from categorizing those parts as rhythm guitar, as the players are clearly doing more than just playing chords; they often switch to melodic passages. In the bluegrass example (the third video), the supporter even tells me to "see the solos in the second part of the recording," inadvertently admitting that the focus shifts away from rhythm guitar playing.

@Lazy - (3) Furthermore, even in the solo parts—and in all the videos except the first—you can see that the right hand is, in fact, repeating the same pattern throughout the entire piece. Yes, the pattern is played quickly, which requires a lot of practice, but it remains a single, repeated pattern nonetheless. In contrast, the left hand is consistently performing a far more diverse set of tasks, moving up and down the neck.

@Lazy - (4) The very fact that the right hand, unlike the left, generally doesn’t move up and down the strings (with the exception of certain specialized techniques, none of which are featured in these videos) very clearly demonstrates that the left hand carries a significantly larger burden.
And, of course, playing any instrument is about the coordination between both hands, so even if the right hand is playing a rapid pattern (as in the bluegrass example), this inherently increases the demand on the left hand as well.

@brilliant You criticize my examples, but your only counterexample is of a beginner trying to survive. Please see the first point of my answer. Yes, both hands must be synchronized, but it's the right hand which primarily affects certain crucial features of music. Yes, right hand parts are often repetitive, but still more laborious, while requiring high precision and consistency. Please see the answers from the linked duplicate. Of course you can have your own view. What you do with instrument is personal and related to your own artistic journey.

@user1079505 (1) "You criticize my examples, but your only counterexample is of a beginner trying to survive."

This was not the only counterexample but one of many. However, I chose not to bring up any more because the last three of your videos already serve as good counterexamples. They demonstrate that, as I have already mentioned to Lazy in the comments, the dexterity required of the left hand is greater than that of the right hand.


@user1079505 (2) "but it's the right hand which primarily affects certain crucial features of music"

The point was not about which hand primarily affects crucial features but rather which hand is assigned a more versatile role.


@user1079505 (3) "Yes, right hand parts are often repetitive, but still more laborious, while requiring high precision and consistency"

Which is exactly what I disagree with. High precision and consistency are required FOR BOTH HANDS. However, unlike the left hand, the right hand never has to "fly" from one end of the neck to the other to be positioned at a specific spot in a specific way within a specific time frame. Furthermore, techniques such as string bending and sliding are exclusively performed by the left hand.


@user1079505 (4) By the way, I just want to say that I wouldn’t classify anything I’ve said here as criticism of your answer. As you mentioned, I can have my own view, and you can have yours, but expressing disagreement is not necessarily criticism.

@brilliant So you are talking solely about rhythm guitar? The guitar is much older than the role of rhythm guitar, so it would be weird to switch technique for just rhythm guitar only. Also you seem to assume that in music you have a strong hand and a weak hand. This is in fact not true. Most instruments require quite specific skill in both hands. And if you — as you said — strongly disagree that right hand dexterity mattered for guitar playing then I’m not sure if I can take this seriously.
